# Question about the mechanism of the ArrayList

Tags: java

Basically, when I passed arguments in Java, I knew it was passing only value.

However, the following code shows that the add method executed on `SubClass`'s `SubMethod` affects `ArrayList` of `MainClass`.

MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass{
    public satatic void main(String[] args){
        List list = new ArrayList<>();
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass(list);
        subClass.subMethod();
        System.out.println(list) // Why added value???
    }
}
```

SubClass.java

```
public class SubClass{
    private List list;
    public SubClass(List list){
        this.list = list;
        
    }
    public void subMethod(){
       list.add(1);
       list.add(2);
    }
}
```

When I did the same thing with a `HashMap`'s `put`, there was no effect on the `HashMap` of the `MainClass`.

I would like to know why only `ArrayList` is causing these results and what is happening inside Java.

### Update

The code for the hashmap version is as follows:
MainClass.java

```
public class MainClass{
    public satatic void main(String[] args){
        Map map = new HashMap<>();
        SubClass subClass = new SubClass(map );
        subClass.subMethod();
        System.out.println(map) // Not putting value
    }
}
```

SubClass.java

```
public class SubClass{
    private Map map;
    public SubClass(Map map){
        this.map= map;
        
    }
    public void subMethod(){
       map = someGenerationHashMap(arg1, arg2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code for the `HashMap` version? Because they should behave the same way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Comment: Java passes objects by references. It means Your `SubClass` and `MainClass` share the same list. It is different when You pas a cardinal values like int, long, boolean, etc (note the lowercase). Version with `HashMap` - It will also affect the `HashMap`. Can You please share the code with `HashMap`, there has to be some difference.

Comment: Update My code.

Comment: System.out.println (map) is just simplified code. The problem is that in that situation HashMap.isEmpty is true.

Comment: Forget what I said, it was wrong. `HashMap`'s `toString` method returns the content as well, so it should print. See Andres' answer for the actual reason (i.e., you're not adding to the map, you're creating a new one and losing the reference immediately after that)

Comment: `someGenerationHashMap` reassigns new map to `map`. It means that maps in `MainClass` and `SubClass` are not referrring the same one.

Answer (score 2):

It's not about ArrayList. Any object you pass as an argument can be modified. What is passed by value is the address of the object, not the object itself.

In the Map version, you are not making any operation that could modify it. In the list version instead, you are making an add.

Make sure not to confuse objects with primitives. For example, make sure not to confuse `int` with `Integer`.